# Insert UI elements into existing layouts

Tags: python, layout, maya, maya-api

I want to insert a button into the main status line in Maya, it is the line where the functions like, save scene, vertex snap, open render view and stuff like this is([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AawVx.png)).

I already can add a button to the line, but it gets appended all the way to the right.
But how do I insert it between already existing buttons?
I want for example that my button is between the "Open Renderview" and "Render the current frame" button.

The code adds a button to the status line in Maya:

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds
MainStatusLineLayoutChildren = cmds.layout('MainStatusLineLayout', query = True, childArray = True)

a = cmds.layout(MainStatusLineLayoutChildren[0], query = True, childArray = True)

cmds.nodeIconButton('testIconButton', style = 'iconOnly', image1 = 'file.png', parent = a[0])
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily, if you know Qt, you can take the layout pointer and use the insert method. I've not seen any insert flag in cmds unfortunatly. I can give you an example on how it can be done if you are not afraid to use Qt

Comment: I already thought that it wasnt possible in cmds, but I would love to see the qt approach

Comment: Looks like that underlying layout is a `QLayout` object, which makes this a bit more tricky since `QLayout` doesn't have an insert method..